# Twisted PPA not working for Ubuntu Saucy?

Tags: ubuntu, twisted

I just tried to update Twisted via **ppa:twisted-dev/ppa** but I get the following error message when running sudo apt-get update:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/twisted-dev/ppa/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Hopefully it's just a matter of someone doing some maintenance to get it functional.
I'd really like to move to 13.2

Couldn't find the bug tracker to report this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was advised by the Twisted release manager that the ppa is not as reliable a source for updates as Pypi.  He advised doing a pip install --upgrade instead of relying on apt-get-update/upgrade.

That worked and it's fine except that it means we have to remember to do Twisted upgrades in a different manner than many other programs.  It's easy to remember (or automate) apt-get.  It's another easily forgettable step to have to do the pip upgrade.  If we automate the pip upgrade that's adding another level of complexity that I don't think should be necessary.

But most important, I understand that there are only so many hours in a day for people to manage and implement Twisted. If there is going to be a ppa then it needs to be kept up to date.  If there isn't time to do the ppa updates then it shouldn't be promoted as a method of updating.